# Bootstrap not responsive, yet I have the meta tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Alright, it seems bootstrap just quit on me. (its kinda late, so sorry if this is because of something stupid)

Anyway, it seems bootstrap stopped changing when the width is lower. Now, it just tries squishing it together. Example(x = left content y = right content):

Normal:

```
xxxxxxxxx yyy
```

When width is smaller:

```
xxx yy
```

And it should be:

```
x
y
```

(meta tag is included correctly!)

Site can be located at http://tst.burngames.net/Burn%20Games/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your sidebar and main content box in the same row. The side bar wraps under when you remove the row and does not squash up to fit on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the bootstrap.responsive.js file.